# How to get "this" to not be undefined from method in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I can't seem to get a property in my data object to display. Any help greatly appreciated.

```js
const people = [{
    name: "Joe Smith",
    address: "123 hello street",
    cityStateZip: "tampa, fl 12345"
  },
  {
    name: "Alan Jones",
    address: "123 hello street",
    cityStateZip: "nyc, ny 12345"
  },
  {
    name: "Tina Roberts",
    address: "123 hello street",
    cityStateZip: "san diego, ca 12345"
  }
]

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    people: people
  },
  methods: {
    getAddress() {
      return '' + this.address + '';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="person in people" class="box">
    <h1>{{person.name}}</h1>
    <a v-text="getAddress()"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I access the data to print it through a method? Thanks.

Comment: `getAddress(person)` and use the variable passed in.

Comment: Though I'm not sure why you need that method with `person.address` would give it to you.

Comment: I need to use it in a broader function than just getting one property, I was just looking for the general explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reference this, it is refering to your vue component but in your Vue component you only define one `data` element, `people: people`. In order to make your method work, you need to send in a parameter to your method and use the passed parameter instead of `this`.

HTML: `<a v-text="getAddress(person)"></a>`

JS:

```
    getAddress(person) {
      return '' + person.address + '';
    }
```

But you could easily do this without needing the method at all with:

```
  <div v-for="person in people" class="box">
    <h1>{{person.name}}</h1>
    <a v-text="person.address"></a>
  </div>
```